# angularjs checked box in form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, checkbox

I want to when edit user to fill all field in form automatically. I managed to fill input and select fields, but don't know how to do that with checkbox, to be checked if they need to be checked. As a matter of fact I did but after a few days that solution stopped working even nothing has changed. I wrote my code in this way:
html

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="admin" ng-model="userDataCtr.user.admin"  ng-checked="userDataCtr.user.admin">ROLE_CRO</label>
```

And value of userDataCtr.user.admin is 1, but checkbox isn't checked. I tried with integer, string, but nothing happened.

Does anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The value of a checkbox is boolean- so `userDataCtr.user.admin` should be either `true` or `false`.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="admin" 
   ng-model="userDataCtr.user.admin">ROLE_CRO</label>
```

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

**EDIT**
As @Harris Weinstein points out in the comment to this answer below, you should not use ng-checked and ng-model together.

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Comment: You should add a reference to the [ng-checked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) documentation, which specifically states that it should _not_ be used with `ng-model`.

Comment: I know you didn't; Sasa did. Your point about using a boolean is fine (though a `1` could be interpreted as truthy by Angular), but I think your answer will help Sasa more if you point out the active hindrance of the conflicting directives that's warned against in the documentation.

Comment: If I just type 1 in ng-checked checkbox is checked, but if I send number 1 as value (userDataCtr.user.admin) then isn't checked

Comment: @Sasa I suggest you take out `value` and `ng-checked` entirely, and _only_ use `ng-model`. It's all you need, and the other attributes potentially clash with it.

Comment: I changed value to true and false and now works. I was trying that a couple of times and didn't but now somehow does work. I am confused.